# Анимация спрайтов не один раз

Tags: javascript, функции, анимация, оптимизация

Я хотела сделать так, чтобы вся информация о спрайте хранилась в объекте и функцию отрисовки можно было бы использовать много раз не только с одинаковыми спрайтами. Но ошибку найти не могу. Если консолить все данные, которые приходят в функцию, то sx, который должен меняться, остаётся тем же почему-то

```js
    const canvas = document.getElementById('field');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    let cat = {
        sx: 0,
        tick_count: 0,
        width: 96,
        height: 96,
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        end: 288,
        one: 96,
    };

    let sprite = new Image();
    sprite.src = 'https://ratnotes.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/animal-2a.png';
    sprite.onload = function () {
        tick();
        requestAnimationFrame(tick); //вызов анимации
    };

    function tick() {
        if (cat.tick_count > 10) {
            draw(sprite, ctx, cat.x, cat.y, cat.width, cat.height, cat.sx, cat.end, cat.one, 0);
            cat.tick_count = 0;
        }
        cat.tick_count += 1;
        requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    }

    function draw(image, place, xGen, yGen, widthGen, heightGen, sxGen, endPoint, sizeOfOnePoint, syGen) {
        place.clearRect(xGen, yGen, widthGen, heightGen); //очистка канваса
        sxGen = (sxGen === endPoint ? 0 : sxGen + sizeOfOnePoint); //переброс в начало, если спрайт закончился 384 - width картинки, 384/4 =96 -шаг, на который сдвигаем
        place.drawImage(image, sxGen, syGen, widthGen, widthGen, xGen, yGen, widthGen, widthGen); //отображение первого спрайта
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="field" width="900" height="400">hi</canvas>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы нигде не меняете `sx`, когда Вы передали его в функцию, функция получила просто число, а не ссылку на переменную в объекте cat.

Вам необходимо либо результат смещения из функции и присвоить его в переменную явно.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('field');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let cat = {
  sx: 0,
  tick_count: 0,
  width: 96,
  height: 96,
  x: 100,
  y: 50,
  end: 288,
  one: 96,
};

let sprite = new Image();
sprite.src = 'https://ratnotes.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/animal-2a.png';
sprite.onload = function() {
  tick();
  requestAnimationFrame(tick); //вызов анимации
};

function tick() {
  if (cat.tick_count > 10) {
    cat.sx = draw(sprite, ctx, cat.x, cat.y, cat.width, cat.height, cat.sx, cat.end, cat.one, 0);
    cat.tick_count = 0;
  }
  cat.tick_count += 1;
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}

function draw(image, place, xGen, yGen, widthGen, heightGen, sxGen, endPoint, sizeOfOnePoint, syGen) {
  // очистка канваса
  place.clearRect(xGen, yGen, widthGen, heightGen); 
  //переброс в начало, если спрайт закончился 384 - width картинки, 384/4 =96 -шаг, на который сдвигаем
  sxGen = (sxGen === endPoint ? 0 : sxGen + sizeOfOnePoint); 
  //отображение первого спрайта
  place.drawImage(image, sxGen, syGen, widthGen, widthGen, xGen, yGen, widthGen, widthGen); 
  return sxGen
}
```

```html
<canvas id="field" width="900" height="400">hi</canvas>
```

или например передать ссылку на объект в эту функцию, чтобы так или иначе вызвать присвоение

`cat.sx = ...`